# How to tell mex to link with the libstdc++.so.6 in /usr/lib instead of the one in the MATLAB directory?

Tags: linux, matlab, linker, mex

Now mex in MATLAB 2012a only officially supports gcc 4.4.6 but I want to use gcc 4.7 at my own risk. Now If I compile something with mex directly, it will complain that

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/cc1plus:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6:
version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
(required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libppl_c.so.4)

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/cc1plus:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6:
version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
(required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libppl.so.9)
```

By `strings /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep 'GLIBCXX'` I confirm that this `libstdc++.so.6` has that version string. I reviewed `mexopts.sh` and modified the variable `$RPATH` and `$MLIBS` in that script, but it doesn't work. So if I don't use symbolic link, where can I config the path of the `libstdc++.so.6` that mex uses? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create a symbolic link to the gcc 4.7 library so matlab knows to use it. Something like:

```
ln -s {/path/to/file-name} {link-name}
```

If you don't want to use symbolic links, then just define this path in a terminal from which you launch matlab:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/libstdc++.so.6
./matlab
```

Answer (score 12):

> /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/cc1plus: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found

The problem is that when you are building with `mex`, it puts `-L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86` on the link line, and so the linker picks up `libstdc++.so` from there.

If you can't convince `mex` to prepend `-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` first, then I think your only other choice is to remove `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so` (just rename it to e.g. `libstdc++.so.bak`).

Comment: I edited .matlab7rc.sh to prepend the correct path (and verified by 'matlab -n' that it indeed appear before /sys/os/glnx86 in LD_LIBRARY_PATH) -- but I still get the same error... any hint?

Answer (score 9):

It's a late answer, but I believe the cleanest, most Mathworks-approved and least invasive solution is to edit the `.matlab7rc.sh` script. This is a script used by the `matlab` script when you start MATLAB under UNIX-like systems. (See http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html)

Copy that script (found under `{matlabroot}/bin`) to the root of your project, or to your home directory. Then tell MATLAB to first search in the system directories for the C++ libraries, instead of its own directories. On my system I changed line 191:

```
191c191
<       LDPATH_PREFIX='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
---
>       LDPATH_PREFIX=''
```

(Simply setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the empty string is not a good solution, because that will prevent you from loading other third-party libraries.)

When this is done you might get the following message when running `mex`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

This usually means that `g++` is not installed. On a Debian-like system, run:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

From here on, you might still get an annoying warning about using a version of gcc beyond what is officially supported, but that is harmless and can be ignored.

Comment: That seemed like the perfect solution for me, since I am compiling with no root privileges. Indeed typing 'matlab -n' shows that the path to my local version of libstdc++ (from gcc 4.9) is first in the list of LD_LIBRARY_PATH. However, calling my mex still invokes an error which implies matlab still tries to load it's own libstdc++... any hint?

Comment: The problem was that mexopts.sh still linked with `-lstdc++`, once I removed it, I can compile a mex file against local version of libstdc++, and it runs ok.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, that after a fresh install of Matlab 2016b on Ubuntu 14.04, that I got the "cannot find -lstdc++' error. The above hint made it clear that I just needed to install g++. This was also verified by getting an error typing "mex -setup cpp" at the Matlab prompt. Installed as shown above, and didn't even need to restart Matlab. Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly what I need to get Stan working inside Matlab on a cluster managed by SLURM. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

i tried both the answers.. but none worked for me.

however this worked for me. in matlab run this -

```
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '');
```

just for anyone who is facing the same problem.

P.S: I found this solution [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/47064)

Answer (score 2):

You can modify `~/.matlab/R2012a/mexopts.sh` that generated after doing `mex -setup` by adding a line in glnx86 section:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

or in glnx64:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have root access then you can try,
`LD_PRELOAD='path/to/libstdc++.so.6.0.21' matlab`

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find where my libstdc++.so.6 is, so I was not able to fully test the solution given by geek_girl. However, a modification of th1rdey3's worked. I ran in the matlab console:

```
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', 'usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnxa64:/usr/lib/boost_1_54_0/libs/regex/build/gcc');
```

This is the value I use for 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' when compiling my C++ code in Eclipse (I am not using mex files, instead I create an executable of my C++ code in Eclipse and later run it from matlab shell). In my case the value of 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' is that long because my C++ code uses boost's regex, matlab libraries (libmat, libmx and so on), GSL library and Armadillo. If you don't use all these libraries, setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH','') should be enough, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

On Matlab R2015b, I first relinked `libstdc++.so.6` and then edited `.matlab7rc.sh` as described above by @lindelof. On my desktop, from terminal:

```
locate libstdc++.so.6
```

In my case, the system library is located in `/usr/lib64`. Then

```
cd /usr/local/matlab/sys/os/glnxa64
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstc++.so.6 libstc++.so.6
cd /usr/local/src/matlab/bin/glnxa64/
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstc++.so.6 libstc++.so.6
```

Then edit `.matlab7rc.sh` in `{matlabroot}/bin`. Delete in the same directory any `mexopts.sh` file. Restart Matlab. `MEX` your file from scratch (this will build a new `mexopts.sh` file with the new settings. Run it from Matlab console.