# Matlab R2012a crashes when trying 3D-graphics on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

I'm having problems with my 3D-plotting on Ubuntu 12.10. The crash occurs immeadiately after I try to plot data in 3D. I have Crash dump and other error report here:

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/nouveau_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (/home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so))
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/nouveau_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/nouveau_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/nouveau_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.1.so.1))
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

CRASH DUMP:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Wed Dec 19 02:17:00 2012
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding  : Disabled
  Current Visual  : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding: UTF-8
  GNU C Library   : 2.15 stable
  MATLAB Root     : /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a
  MATLAB Version  : 7.14.0.739 (R2012a)
  Operating System: Linux 3.5.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 13 17:48:01 UTC 2012 x86_64
  Processor ID    : x86 Family 31 Model 6 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD
  Virtual Machine : Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System   : The X.Org Foundation (11300000), display :0.0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 0000000000000000
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 00007fb9ac068658
  RSP = 00007fb9bb8e38e8  RBP = 00000000009a0005
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 0000000000000000

   R8 = 00007fb9ac068680   R9 = 0000000000000000
  R10 = 0000000000000000  R11 = 0000000000000000
  R12 = 0000000000001f02  R13 = 0000000000000000
  R14 = 00007fb9c6b797d0  R15 = 0000000000000000

  RIP = 00007fb973df6d00  EFL = 0000000000010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007fb9d09f592e   /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so+00370990 _ZN2fl4diag15stacktrace_base7captureERKNS0_14thread_contextEm+000158
[  1] 0x00007fb9d09f87d0   /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so+00382928
[  2] 0x00007fb9d09f8b3b   /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so+00383803 _ZN2fl4diag13terminate_logEPKcRKNS0_14thread_contextE+000171
[  3] 0x00007fb9cf8dc203  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01253891 _ZN2fl4diag13terminate_logEPKcPK8ucontext+000067
[  4] 0x00007fb9cf8d90fd  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01241341
[  5] 0x00007fb9cf8da79d  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01247133
[  6] 0x00007fb9cf8da925  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01247525
[  7] 0x00007fb9cf8daf01  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01249025
[  8] 0x00007fb9cf8db3f5  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01250293
[  9] 0x00007fb9cdfa2cb0              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00064688
[ 10] 0x00007fb973df6d00          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0+00056576 xcb_glx_get_string_string_length+000000
[ 11] 0x00007fb97c98a6b4          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1+00272052 __glXGetString+000068
[ 12] 0x00007fb97c98812e          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1+00262446
[ 13] 0x00007fb97cbbf379     /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/glren.so+00078713
[ 14] 0x00007fb97cbb6b40     /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/glren.so+00043840
[ 15] 0x00007fb97cbb6cc6     /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/glren.so+00044230
[ 16] 0x00007fb9c68d30a8   /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+09408680 _Z22OpenGLSetupEnumstrOnceb+000296
[ 17] 0x00007fb9c6827ac7   /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+08706759 gf_DetermineBestRenderMode+000183
[ 18] 0x00007fb9c6827c0b   /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+08707083 _Z22gf_DetermineRenderModeP11GObject_tagi+000107
[ 19] 0x00007fb9c6827d0a   /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+08707338 InitializeFigureRenderEngine+000074
[ 20] 0x00007fb9c6828114   /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+08708372
[ 21] 0x00007fb9c689418c   /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+09150860
[ 22] 0x00007fb9c684a89b   /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+08849563 _Z24commitHG1DatabaseUpdatesb+000235
[ 23] 0x00007fb9d0157e16 /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+01359382 _Z26svWS_CommitDatabaseUpdates28svCommitDatabaseUpdatesType_+000390
[ 24] 0x00007fb9c5030387  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00525191
[ 25] 0x00007fb9c5030691  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00525969
[ 26] 0x00007fb9cfb476eb /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00124651
[ 27] 0x00007fb9cfb47cde /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00126174 _Z10ioReadLinebP8_IO_FILEPcS1_iPbRKN5boost8optionalIKP15inWorkSpace_tagEEb+000990
[ 28] 0x00007fb9cfb48165 /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00127333
[ 29] 0x00007fb9cfb4cd0a /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00146698
[ 30] 0x00007fb9cfb4d165 /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00147813
[ 31] 0x00007fb9cfb4d9ce /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00149966 mnParser+000702
[ 32] 0x00007fb9cf8c0de2  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01142242 _ZN11mcrInstance30mnParser_on_interpreter_threadEv+000034
[ 33] 0x00007fb9cf8a351a  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01021210
[ 34] 0x00007fb9cf8a3598  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01021336
[ 35] 0x00007fb9c5021376  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00463734
[ 36] 0x00007fb9c502b862  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00505954
[ 37] 0x00007fb9d01599a1 /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+01366433 _ZSt8for_eachIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPN5boost8weak_ptrIN4sysq10ws_ppeHookEEESt6vectorIS6_SaIS6_EEEENS4_8during_FIS6_NS2_10shared_ptrIS5_EEEEET0_T_SH_SG_+000081
[ 38] 0x00007fb9d015aaab /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+01370795
[ 39] 0x00007fb9d01585f9 /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+01361401 _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+000665
[ 40] 0x00007fb9cf8a276f  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01017711
[ 41] 0x00007fb9cf8a2c3b  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01018939
[ 42] 0x00007fb9cf8a2d97  /home/jonne/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+01019287
[ 43] 0x00007fb9cdf9ae9a              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00032410
[ 44] 0x00007fb9cdcc7cbd                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+00998589 clone+000109
```

Does anyone have any idea what should I do to get this work? 2D-plotting works, but 3D-does not...

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What renderer are you using? Could you post a code snippet of your script?

Try creating the figure first, a specifying the renderer. For example,

```
figure('renderer','zbuffer')
```

I've had more luck with the `zbuffer` renderer than `opengl` or `painters` for example. In fact, in my startup script I've ensured every figure window that I open uses zbuffer - I've found it is much quicker to render, and has less problems with random crashes.

See: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html

> Renderer
> painters | zbuffer | OpenGL
>
> Rendering method used for screen and printing. Selects the method used to render MATLAB  graphics. The choices are:
>
> painters — The original rendering method used by MATLAB is faster when the figure contains only simple or small graphics objects.
>
> zbuffer — MATLAB draws graphics objects faster and more accurately because it colors objects on a per-pixel basis and MATLAB renders only those pixels that are visible in the scene (thus eliminating front-to-back sorting errors). Note that this method can consume a lot of system memory if MATLAB is displaying a complex scene.
>
> OpenGL — OpenGL is a renderer that is available on many computer systems. This renderer is generally faster than painters or zbuffer and in some cases enables MATLAB to access graphics hardware that is available on some systems.

Comment: Thank you!! I changed the renderer to zbuffer and VOILA! =D I think I had OpenGL. My code was:                                          [x,y] = meshgrid([-2:.2:2]);
Z = x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2);
surf(x,y,Z,gradient(Z))

Answer (score 3):

This helped me: 
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154775
 (...which got help from [How to tell mex to link with the libstdc++.so.6 in /usr/lib instead of the one in the MATLAB directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959306/how-to-tell-mex-to-link-with-the-libstdc-so-6-in-usr-lib-instead-of-the-one-i))

basically I just did this:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6__bck
```

and

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6
```