# Matlab R2016a Mex file error

Tags: c++, matlab, gcc

I have gcc version 5.3.1 on fedora 23 and I want to run some mex files. Whe I  compile the file I get the following warning:

Warning: You are using gcc version '5.3.1-6)'. The version of gcc is not supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For a list of currently supported compilers
see: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release.

and when I try to run it I get the following error :

Invalid MEX-file '/home/x/Downloads/MatlabEXR/MatlabEXR/exrread.mexa64': /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not
found (required by /home/x/Downloads/MatlabEXR/MatlabEXR/exrread.mexa64)

I tried this : [How to tell mex to link with the libstdc++.so.6 in /usr/lib instead of the one in the MATLAB directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959306/how-to-tell-mex-to-link-with-the-libstdc-so-6-in-usr-lib-instead-of-the-one-i)

but still I get the same error. Anything in mind what can be the problem?

Comment: The error is very clear.  You are using a newer compiler than the one that MEX supports.  You have to use gcc 4.7.x so that it's compatible with MEX.  See this link from MathWorks for more details: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2016a/index.html?sec=glnxa64

Comment: how can I have both gcc-4.7 and gcc 5.3.1 and link matlab to the older version?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem regarding libstdc++(I couldn't plot anything). This is the link to my question. [matlab on linux can't plot anything(can't load libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473597/matlab-on-linux-cant-plot-anythingcant-load-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1/38731168#38731168)

How I solved the issue is also stated there.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You error is originated from the fact that your libstdc++ uses a new ABI by default (https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html). You can't link your MEX files using gcc 5.xx version.