# matlab on linux can't plot anything(can't load libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found)

Tags: linux, matlab, plot, fedora

I'm running matlab R2016a on Fedora 24 and I can't use the plot command.

This is the error I get:

> `Error using gca`
>
> `While setting the 'Parent' property of 'Axes':`
>
> `Can't load
>   '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwosgserver.so':
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6:
>   version 'CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib64/libGLU.so.1)`
>
> `Error in newplot (line 73)`
>
> ```
> ax = gca(fig);
> ```

Also I have seen 
[How to fix: [program name] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by [program name])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/how-to-fix-program-name-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxx)
and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What I did was I edited a file called .matlab7rc.sh (located in "path_to_ matlab/bin" folder and its hidden) and uncommented all lines that were(there are several of them):

`LDPATH_PREFIX='$MATLAB/sys/opengl/lib/$ARCH'`

The following is stated in the file for uncommenting this line(s)

> To always use the OpenGL libraries shipped with MATLAB uncomment the next
>   line.

Although it certainly did the trick I'm curious whether using OpenGL that was shipped with MATLAB degrades the performance and in general how does this approach compares to @joe_st_amand's answer.

Comment: This also solves an issue of MATLAB not closing when you attempt to exit, and instead stalling and saying "Busy" for all eternity. From here (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/299126-r2016a-on-linux-fedora-24-will-not-exit) but also relevant to Ubuntu 16.10 in my case.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with that version of matlab and fedora. It seems that matlab prepends its own library paths on startup to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

You can start up matlab with and tell it to use the right version of libstdc++ using the following:
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 matlab -desktop

What I did was add an alias to my .bashrc file:
alias matlab='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 matlab -desktop'

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate fix:

Rename the libstdc++.so.6 library file so that MATLAB cannot find it and is forced to use the system's version of the library. This file is located in matlabroot/sys/os/glnxa64/

Source: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/329796-issue-with-libstdc-so-6

I tried and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked in fedora 28 scientific

```
> cd ~/usr/lib64
> ls libstd*
```

For me the output was

```
libstdc++.so.6  libstdc++.so.6.0.25
```

So I just added an alias in `~/.bashrc` with the directory to `libstdc++.so.6.0.25`

```
> emacs ~/.bashrc
```

Write following line at the end:

```
alias matlab='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.025  /your/dir/to/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB -desktop'
```

Where `/your/dir/to/` is the directory of your MATLAB installation. Then

```
> source ~/.bashrc
```

and after that I just run `> matlab` in terminal and all is OK.

**EDIT. Add it to a desktop entry**

You must make/edit a matlab.desktop file with the following, and place it in your `.applications` folder in order to works.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Matlab R2017a
Exec=LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/matlab -desktop &
Icon=~/username/.icons/Matlab_Logo.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;Science;Education
```

When opening from the desktop entry, it will load the appropiate libstdc. Works well.